# How can I debug a SQL Server trigger that is giving error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime, triggers

I have a C# app with a SQL Server backend. In the backend I have two tables:

1. `MyTable`
2. `MyTableHistory`

I just added a trigger to put an entry in `MyTableHistory` when you do an update on `MyTable`. I am getting and error when I add this trigger:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

Here is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TU_MyTable]
ON dbo.[MyTable]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   INSERT INTO dbo.[MyTableHistory]
       SELECT * 
       FROM deleted
   GO
```

Here is my table schema

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[MyTable] 
(
    [Id] int IDENTITY NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY,
    [Timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] bit NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(200) NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdated] datetime NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdatedBy] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
)
GO
```

and here is the history table schema

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[MyTableHistory] 
(
    [Id] int NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] binary(8) NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] bit NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTableHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([Id], [Timestamp]),
    [LastUpdated] datetime NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdatedBy] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(200) NOT NULL
)
GO
```

Is there anyway to figure out what field is causing this issue and is there anyway to debug inside the database trigger to help me diagnose?

Comment: Definition of timestamp on the non-history table is??? Also, your columns aren't in the same order, so of course a select * without specifying names is going to break.

Comment: Have a look here too: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to conversion of `NVARCHAR` to `DATETIME`. In `MyTable`, the column `Name` is placed before the `LastUpdated` column. In short, the order of columns in both tables is not the same. You should specify the columns in your `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO MyTableHistory(
    Id,
    [Timestamp],
    IsDeleted,
    Name,
    LastUpdated,
    LastUpdatedBy
)
    SELECT
        Id,
        [Timestamp],
        IsDeleted,
        Name,
        LastUpdated,
        LastUpdatedBy
    FROM deleted
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing an `insert` without a column list is dangerous.  Include the list and don't use `*`:

```
Insert into dbo.[MyTableHistory]([Id], [Timestamp], [IsDeleted], [LastUpdated],
                                [LastUpdatedBy], [Name])
    SELECT  id, [Timestamp], IsDeleted, LastUpdated, LastUpdatedBy, Name
    from deleted;
```

Do not depend on the ordering of columns in a table -- it causes bugs that are hard to find.